# How do I "Search All Mailboxes" in all Outlook Shared Mailbox Folders at once via c#?

Tags: c#, linq, outlook, ienumerable

I want to mimic the latest version of Outlook's search functionality via c# and a windows form. Specifically, I want to "Search All Mailboxes" for a given string.  There are over 50 folders and 90,000 emails.

Currently, I am able to search any one folder using LINQ and get results. I wrote some code to iterate through all the folders and create one massive `IEnumerable<MailItem>` that I can query.

```
public IEnumerable<MailItem> SharedInbox
{
    get
    {
        outlook.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Outlook.Recipient recip = Outlook.Application.Session.CreateRecipient("TOCCard@Capitalone.Com");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder folder =
                    outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Folders subFolders = folder.Folders;
        IEnumerable<MailItem> mItems  = folder.Folders[1].Items.OfType<MailItem>();
            
        if (recip.Resolve())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Email Address Resolve Successful.\r\n");

            try
            {
                foreach (MAPIFolder fold in subFolders)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Try Folder: " + fold.Name + " \r\n");

                    try
                    {
                        mItems = mItems.Concat(fold.Items.OfType<MailItem>());
                    }
                    catch
                    { 
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No items found:\r\n"); 
                    }
                }

                return mItems;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ELSE");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This eventually works, but you can probably imagine that this excruciatingly slow and as such is useless.

I am new to LINQ and I feel like there must be a faster way. Can this code be adjusted? I am not an Exchange admin and have no access to the exchange servers beyond my own inbox. Also I am not married to LINQ and would be happy to use other methods. I will appreciate your help.

NOTE: I just noticed that the above code is going through folder[1] twice. I can fix that, but it is not significantly affecting the time it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not use LINQ with OOM. Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.

You can also use `Aplication.AdvancedSearch` (keep in mind it is asynchronous).